# Why doesn't this LINQ query work as expected?

Tags: c#, linq

Assume I have a class called MyClass that has two properties (int Id and a string Name). I want to populate a List of these MyClass objects from another collection but I want only the unique ones. This other collection is a 3rd party object that has a property named 'Properties' that is just an array of values, the first two of which correspond to the Id and Name values I care about. There can be duplicates in this collection so I want only the unique ones.

It seems like this should do the trick but it does not, it returns all the items regardless of dupes. What am I doing wrong here?

```
List<MyClass> items = (from MyClass mc in collectionOfProps 
select new MyClass() { 
Id = collectionOfProps.Properties[0], 
Name = collectionOfProps.Properties[1] }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: looking at your query, it looks good to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is likely that `MyClass` does not implement [`IEquatable<MyClass>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) as well as override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

In order to make `Distinct()` work the way you want, you have to implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx).  Otherwise, it uses the default (reference equality) for checking, which means it would only determine the elements were not distinct if they were the same exact instance.

Comment: [This page](http://blog.jordanterrell.com/post/LINQ-Distinct()-does-not-work-as-expected.aspx) seems to explain why implementing `IEquatable<MyClass>` won't necessarily fix the problem, in and of itself.

Comment: @Brian: He needs `GetHashCode()` too.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, but stuffing a `GetHashCode` into an `IEqualityComparer` won't help either (putting it in the type *will* help, obviously).  Anyhow, the person in that article was trying to avoid `GetHashCode` and was forced to do a bit ugly to accomplish his goal.

Comment: @Brian Note that, if you read the docs for `IEquatable<T>`, it explicitly mentions that you should always override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` when implementing the interface.  "Proper" implementation of `IEquatable<T>` implies that you implement all three, even though only the one method is defined by the interface.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: You're right.  Further, the documentation for [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) explicitly states to implement `IEquatable`.  Though reading the documentation more carefully (i.e., by ignoring its brief explanation of the Default Comparator and instead reading the [linked documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx)) shows that it is sufficient to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @Brian: It also shows, however, that it will use `IEquatable<T>` if available, which typically is better, especially if you're dealing with value types...

Comment: Thanks Reed, this was my own dumb mistake, I had implemented Equals and GetHashCode but omitted the IEquatable from the class def so it obviously was not working as expected, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `Equals()` **and `GetHashCode()`** to compare instances by value.

Comment: SLaks is correct.  At least in .Net 4.0, `Distinct` is implemented using a `Set` (`internal` framework class which is similar to a `HashSet`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you overridden equality (for distinct) in MyClass? My guess would be no.

According to the docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx

> The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of the types that implement the IEquatable(Of T) generic interface. To compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type.