# LINQ query not returning unique rows

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query which queries SQL Express database through Entity Framework but doesn't return unique rows when written this way in Visual Studio:

```
var q = from s in _db.SD
        where s.ID == ID && s.Time >= startDate && s.Time <= endDate
        select s
```

It returns correct number of rows but each row has same data as first one. However, when I tested the same query in LinqPad the result returned is fine i.e. correct number of rows and unique data in each row.

Secondly, if I try to change the statment to this:

```
var q = from s in _db.SD
        where s.ID == ID && s.Time >= startDate && s.Time <= endDate
        select s.Data
```

Then I got correct number of rows and unique value in each row. 
Can someone please help me find out the problem with code?

Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
Here's full function:

```
public List<SD> GetHistory(int ID, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var q = (from s in _db.SD
            where s.ID == ID &&
            s.Time >= startDate && s.Time <= endDate
            select s).ToList();

   return q;
}
```

Comment: Please post your models

Comment: it's not possible.probably you are doing something wrong.Can you show us how are you using the returning result  ?

Comment: Just refresh your edmx file and try.

Comment: public class SD
    {
        [Key]
        public Int16 ID { get; set; }
        public Byte MT { get; set; }
        public Byte Data { get; set; }
        public Byte SS { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I have shortened the names of properties to retain privacy.

Comment: I am using toList() on var q and returning that from the function.

Comment: @Usman Khalid: I don't have edmx file in my project. Just classes for SQL tables.

Comment: Post the way you tested.

Comment: Here's the full function: public List<SD> GetHistory(int ID, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            var q = (from s in _db.SD
                         where s.ID == ID &&
                               s.Time >= startDate && s.Time <= endDate
                         select s).ToList();

           return q;
        }

Comment: How about doing a .Distinct() in the query?

Comment: Are you sure the database you used in LINQPad is the same you use in VS?

Comment: Yes the database is same. Even the first row that is being returned contains correct data from database. It's just that the same row is being repeated n times instead of n unique rows.

Comment: please see my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting correct distinct data using `select s.Data`, then you can write a `Comparer` class implementing `IEqualityComparer<>` inside the `SD` class as follows:

```
public class SD
{
    public Int16 ID { get; set; }

    public Byte MT { get; set; }
    public Byte Data { get; set; }
    public Byte SS { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<SD>
    {
        public bool Equals(SD x, SD y)
        {
            return x.Data == y.Data; // look...here I m using 'Data' field for distinction
        }

        public int GetHashCode(SD obj)
        {
            unchecked  // overflow is fine
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.Data.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write the `GetHistory()` method passing the `Comparer` in the `Distinct()` method as follows:

```
public List<SD> GetHistory(int ID, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var list = new List<SD>();
    var q = (from s in list
                where s.ID == ID &&
                s.Time >= startDate && s.Time <= endDate
                select s).Distinct(new SD.Comparer()).ToList();

    return q;
}
```

---

### EDIT

The regular query uses the default (reference equality) for checking whether two objects are equal or not.

So, in order to make `Distinct()` work the way you want, you have to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`. Otherwise, it will use the default (reference equality) for checking, which means it would only determine the elements were not distinct if they were the same exact instance. [See the reference here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8126186/1977104)

Comment: Thanks Wasif for your answer. But I still want to understand why regular query won't work on this dataset?

Comment: I have updated my above answer. please see the `EDIT` section there.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. So does that mean that linq query is correct since it gives correct result when run from LINQPad but in order to run it from C# project we need to add these functions. Also, how come in examples for model classes for entity framework they don't mention to implement these function exclusively?

Comment: you can start a separate thread for these new queries. Thanks!